# block text on ckeditor

Tags: jquery, css, ckeditor

I have a problem and I do not know very well how to solve, I need to block a part of a text that is inside `ckeditor` so the user does not delete and does not change that part of the text, but it can complement the text only can not change that part

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            <p> This part can not be changed </ p> <p> This one can </ p>
</textarea>
```

jquery

```
<script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

I thought of some `css` or `javascript` code that blocks this change

Comment: How would a user change the text of a paragraph element? I mean of course if they knew how to open the developer tools and edit the html or use the console window to execute javascript, there is no way to stop them from changing it, but if you mean by just interacting with the user interface, the <p> element is not an editable field.

Comment: You need to show your code, what you have so far?

Comment: if you are always going to have that text then why put it in the editor? why not just put it in the template?  If you need editable text before and after it, then why not have two editable fields instead of one with fixed text inside it?

Comment: @Pete its a variable text, i cant use a template

Comment: If it is variable then how do you know what to put in the editor?  What's the difference between putting it in the editor vs putting it where you finally want to put it? Apart from the latter is easier than putting it in the editor and not allowing someone to edit it